# arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file

Tags: arara

I am really enjoying the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) tool for automating the compilations of my documents- thanks [Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) and the team `:)`

I work on a few projects that have a main file (say `myfile.tex`) that `\include`s its 'chapter' files. A typical example is

**`myfile.tex`**

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{lions}

\end{document}
```

I can run `arara` on this file just fine, and pass options to it (such as `-v` for `verbose` mode).

I would like to be able to run `arara` on my 'chapter' file

**`lions.tex`**

```
% arara: mainfile: {name: myfile}
hello world
```

My first attempt at a 'rule' for `arara` is as follows

**`mainfile.yaml`**

```
!config
# compile mainfile rule for arara
# author: Chris Hughes
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: mainfile
name: The main file is ...
command: arara @{name}
arguments:
- identifier: name
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.name}
```

Although this does work, it isn't really perfect because even if I run

```
arara -v lions.tex
```

the `-v` (and any other options) are ignored because I haven't passed the options through to the command.

So, how can I make an `arara` rule to compile the main file from within a chapter file? If there's a better way of doing this in `arara` I'd like to see that too :)

Comment: This should be a task for the editor. If, in TeXshop, I type the "magic lines" `% !TEX root = ./myfile.tex` and `% !TEX TS-program = arara`, while in `myfile.tex` there are the arara directives, it all works flawlessly. I added an engine file for arara to TeXShop, of course.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sub>First of all, thank you very much for your kind words, Chris. `:)`</sub>

I'm really impressed with Marco's answer suggesting an `arara` inception. `:)` Personally, I prefer a more spartan solution, presented as follows.

As egreg suggested in the comments, if the editor provides `% !TEX root = ...`, `arara` will be executed with the file described in that directive. It's probably the cleanest solution.

I'd suggest to override the `files` directive argument in order to achieve something similar, say

**`main.tex`**

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{lions}

\end{document}
```

**`lions.tex`**

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ main.tex ] }
hello world
```

I simply repeated the rule from the main file, overriding the original reference to the current file and pointing to my main file. The `files` argument directive must be overriden for every `arara` directive.

When calling

```
$ arara lions.tex
```

`arara` will run `pdflatex` on `main.tex` instead of `lions.tex`.

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I like this very much: when one is editing a secondary file, probably full typesetting with all the directives in the main file is not required. Just turn to the main file when the full set of directives is wanted.

Comment: @egreg and '@'Paulo: In my deleted comment I had the same idea. Egred pointed out that this solution unfortunately doesn't handle all compilation rules of the main file. This is the reason for the new rule.

Comment: +1 brilliant, thanks Paulo! I agree with @egreg's comment (although I hadn't originally thought of it). Both solutions are great, and I can see value in both approaches :) I have no idea which one to accept though... :)

Comment: I am afraid my question is naive, but when the main file in a some parent directory, how can I point to it? Does `../` for example apply here?

Answer (score 14):

I want to provide a small solution.

First I want to show your my yaml rule:

```
!config
# Mainfile rule for arara
# author: Marco Daniel
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: mainfile
name: Mainfile
command: <arara> arara @{options} "@{rootfile}"
arguments:
- identifier: rootfile
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.rootfile}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
```

As you can see, you have to options.

1. You can declare the filename of the root file.
2. You can pass options to arara.

To use araras options like `-v` the main executing must allow the argument.

With the following files:

**mainfile.tex**

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{lions}
\end{document}
```

**lions.tex**

```
% arara: mainfile: { rootfile: mainfile , options: --verbose}
hello world as
```

you can execute with:

```
localhost:test marco$ arara -v lions
```

And you will get the following output:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Mainfile... 

  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFLaTeX... 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mainfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 piedmontese, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian
, serbianc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, u
ppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./mainfile.aux
 (./lions.aux)) (./lions.tex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pd
ftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mainfile.aux (./lions.aux)) )</usr/local/texlive/20
12/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mainfile.pdf (1 page, 11949 bytes).
Transcript written on mainfile.log.
Status: SUCCESS

Status: SUCCESS
```