# does LaTeX support native multifile management?

Tags: emacs, external-files, input

This is not really a practical question, but more of an academic one:

I use emacs to write my LaTeX files and in order to process multifile documents I include at the end of each file a local variable `%%% TeX-master: "master"` that tells emacs that when I compile this file I actually want to compile the file "master.tex".

Now I was just wondering if there is a way to do this in LaTeX something like `\setmaster{master}` or `\includedin{master}` that one can simply put in the begining of the file and it tells directly to the compiler it should start looking at the other file first.

Comment: I use `arara` for this: [arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100585) There are a host of other automation tools, but imho, `arara` is king

Comment: @cmhughes: that looks quite nice, but it depends on an alternative compiler. my question was if LaTeX supports the feature natively. As far as my settings go they work pretty fine and I am not thinking of changing any time soon (hence the "academic question")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible, but with important limitations. Let's assume we have `master.tex` and `secondary.tex`.

First of all, how should `\setmaster` be defined? It's quite easy:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setmaster}[1]{%
   % Make all later \setmaster commands to be no-ops
   \global\let\setmaster\@gobble
   % Start reading the master file
   \input{#1}%
   % When it's finished, don't read from this file any more
   \endinput}
\makeatother
```

But *where* should `\setmaster` be defined? Either in the document itself or in a personalized format file. In the first case, surround the definition between `\ifdefined\setmaster\else` and `\fi`, because we don't want to read it when `secondary.tex` is input.

**First limitation.** Paths will be relative to the location of the secondary file, so all files must all be in the same directory: you can't have `\input{../master}` and then `master.tex` call `\input{subdir/secondary}`.

**Second limitation.** TeX sets the job name equal to the first input file, if not overridden from the command line with the option `-jobname`. So, without cooperation from the editor/front-end, you won't get `master.log` or `master.pdf`, but `secondary.log`. This is a built-in behavior of TeX and it can't be modified: as soon as TeX is started and opens a file for input (in this case `secondary.tex`), it opens the `.log` file with the name derived from it or from the `-jobname` command line option.

Thus such an approach is not better than stating what's the main file using the editor's or front-end's features. Many of them have this feature, so this should be the preferred method.

The `arara` methods outlined in the answers to [arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100585/arara-making-a-rule-to-compile-the-main-file-from-a-chapter-file) are worthy of more than a look, because they are independent from whatever editor/front-end is being used.