# How is automatic indentation done for subfiles with arara and latexindent?

Tags: automation, arara, latexindent

I guess that I have overlooked something, but I can't find a solution to run arara on my subfiles when processing my main file. I would like to autoindent my code but only succeed for the `main.tex`.

I installed `latexindent.plx` which works great. If I run `% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes }` on a single file document, everything works like expected.

In my actual documents the `main.tex` will look like this:

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes }
% arara: indent: { trace : yes }
\input{header}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter/foo}
\end{document}
```

For this solution, I get `main.tex` indented beautifully but not the header and not the chapters. As arara is looking for commands all over the source, I added another `% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes }` on top of some subfiles, but they don't effect the process. I would be glad for a hint, where my thinking error is.

Comment: This is the first `latexindent` question- thanks very much for trying it :) I'll do some experiments and get back to you, I have an idea on what to try :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, thanks very much for trying [`latexindent`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) :)

Your question is pretty much exactly the same idea as [arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100585/arara-making-a-rule-to-compile-the-main-file-from-a-chapter-file) and the trick is to tell [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) which files you want to operate on.

As such, the following works as you want.

```
% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes, trace: yes, files: [ chapter/foo.tex, header.tex, chapter/bar.tex ]  }
\input{header}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter/foo}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have combined your two `arara` `indent` directives into one, otherwise you're running it twice- this shouldn't be necessary, and should probably be avoided. If `latexindent` does something wrong on the *first* pass, then the `trace` would have told you what happened on the *second* pass, which wouldn't have been very useful.

Comment: oh that's cool. And beautiful. Works great. Nice feature would be to select all files (or even synced to `\includeonly`) but at first, it gives good control. `main.tex` is not indented now so that the annoying "file changed outside your IDE" is not appearing for all files but the selected ones.

Comment: For a cool "let me indent all your source code for you with the cool tool I found", this solution is a bit unwieldy. I am just thinking of all my .tikz and mydefs.tex-files...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi glad it worked. You can certainly run `latexindent` on a list of files- it sounds like you might need to write a batch script of some kind, which will vary depending on your operating system

Comment: Thank you. I think I am fine for the moment. Maybe IDEs like TC will adapt your script some time... Would be cool.

Comment: If it can help someone: the following code applies `latexindent` to all `tex` files of the current directory, on a Linux shell: `find . -name '*.tex' -exec  latexindent -w $1 -- {} \;`.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou no problem :) when I click on https://github.com/cereda/arara/blob/master/rules/indent.yaml it takes me to a valid file -- have I misunderstood?

Comment: No problem :) feel free to contact me at GitHub if ever you'd like to chat about latexindent:)

Comment: @cmhughes You probably know that but when using intervals of the for `[a,b)`, `latexindent` fails. Now I'm using the package `interval` so it no longer matters for me. Apart from that, would you know how to indent all files in a folder, using arara (and not the command I posted three comments above)?

Comment: @anderstood could you post a complete example in which `latexindent.pl` fails at https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues. I'm not sure how to translate your command into `arara`, that sounds like it could be a new question :)

Comment: will do and [done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392594/indent-all-tex-files-with-arara)