# Batch commands with arara

Tags: arara, workflow

The following Linux command executes the program `<program name>` on all `tex` files in the current directory and subdirectories.

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec `<program name>` -w $1 -- {} \;
```

How can `arara` be used to execute a program in a similar way?

For example, how would I run `latexindent` on all `tex` files without having to specify files as in:

```
% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes, files: [ chapter/foo.tex, header.tex ]  }
```

?

Comment: +1 this question isn't necessarily about `latexindent`. You could equally ask, for example, *how do I tell `arara` to compile all .tex files using `pdflatex` in a directory?*

Comment: @cmhughes Right, I rewrote the question :)

Comment: Why not use `find`? That is, why do you want to use `arara` which is really designed to work with single files, as I understand it.

Comment: @cfr Just to type one easy command (`arara main`) instead of two... That's basically the same reason why I use `arara` instead of `pdflatex`, then `biber`, then etc.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you do them one-by-one. `find` will handle them all. A shell script can handle the `find`, if need be. You don't need this all the time, do you? I think of `arara` invocations as best suited to the things I want to happen every time I compile a document. (Really, just the compilation command, it turns out, though I know some people are fussier and want the biblio and stuff every time, too. Or maybe they just have faster computers.)

Comment: @cfr My use would be batch indenting, so that dozens of `tex` files become indented. I usually compile with pdflatex, and in average every ten compilations, I use `arara`. I would like to indent my codes about as often as I call `arara`. Of course I could make a script calling `find` and also `arara`. I was just wondering whether it could be combined with `arara` (I agree it's not a big deal).

Comment: Oh, I'm the opposite. I mostly compile with `arara`. I don't when I'm compiling TeX SE examples or am getting errors. (`arara` just runs the binary with relevant options - I've never got multiple `arara` lines in a single document to work, but I don't compile the bibliography and stuff as often anyway.)

Comment: The best way to do it would be to write your own custom rule. (Have a look at how the `clean` rule is implemented in `clean.yaml`.) I think `arara` shouldn't be able to execute any arbitrary command for security reasons. (Imagine if the same method was used with `clean` to find and delete all `.tex` files.)