# Indent subfiles with arara (subfiles package)

Tags: arara

Can `bar.tex` file be indented by arara?

`foo.tex` is indented if I use: `% arara: indent: { overwrite: yes  }`, but not `bar.tex`

`foo.tex` file:

```
% arara: indent: { overwrite: yes, files: [ dir/bar.tex ]  }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{dir/bar}

\end{document}
```

##### output

```
11/08/2021 15:18:02), please wait.
(Indent) The latexindent.pl script ......................
FAILURE
Total: 1.03 seconds
Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127300/14757

Comment: @Sigur. Thanks. I read that. Arara is indenting if I use `include` & `input`, but not when I use `\subfile{dir/bar}`

Comment: Deeply sorry for the delay, I really missed your question! There's a miscalculation in the `indent` rule. I just opened an issue: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/76 I can write a workaround for you, if it's too urgent...

Comment: @PauloCereda no urgent at all! I just spotted it! Take your time! Thanks for your work!

Comment: Version 6.1.3 with updated `indent` rule hit TL mirrors today. `:)` Hope it works!