# Compiling multi-file LaTeX file

Tags: compiling, winedt

I have large LaTeX project (my thesis) with a main TeX file and many subfiles contained in their own subdirectories. The template is available [here](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/) at Cambridge University website

Now coming to my question, in WinEdt I can compile the project only when the current document is the main/root document. If I try to run from sub files WinEdt throws an error.

Is there any way (like a flag in LaTeXing for Sublime Text) to tell WinEdt to always start compiling from root TeX file.

Comment: if you use `arara` then [arara: making a rule to compile the main file from a chapter file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100585) will work on any editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change in WinEdt to your main file and press <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> (menu `Project`-> `Set Main File`). The shortcut is available only in WinEdt version 7 and above.

Now you can change to other files, work with them.  If you click now to compile the main file is compiled ...

Comment: This works. However in WinEdt 10, I observed that closing the main file results in error messages. I mean closing it in WinEdt while remaining the 'set main file' entry.