# How to compile the main from a chapter when the main is in another directory (with arara)?

Tags: arara

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100709/101651) works perfectly if the main is in the same directory of the chapter file.

But suppose I have:

```
maindirectory
  main.tex
  chapterdirectory
    chapter.tex
```

How can I compile `main.tex` from `chapter.tex`? (I'm using Windows 10).

I tried with:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ "C:\maindirectory\main.tex" ] }
```

and other various combinations but it seems that `arara` accepts only the file name.

This is the same naive question Diaa Abidou asked in his comment, which remained unanswered, unfortunately.

Comment: `% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ "../main.tex" ] }` works here (Linux) in that `arara` finds and runs `main.tex` in the directory above, but with `\input{chapterdir/chapter}` it fails in that `pdflatex` can't find the file, due to (I think) being run from the `chapterdir` folder, and not the `maindir` folder.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Tonight I'll try "../main.tex" or "..\main.tex" on  Windows and let you know.

Comment: Finding the file is not enough. To compile successfully one should be in the folder of main.tex. So the question is, if arara is allowed to switch into the parent directory of the current directory and then run something there.  I'm not sure that I would like it if this were possible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't imagine it was so complicated

Comment: Paulo just said that in 3.0 it is not possible. arara 4.0 will be able to do it. But be aware that it is a security issue if you can switch to an outside folder. E.g. I have a test folder and if some filecontents-environment goes wrong and overwrites files there I don't care. But if it would delete files in a parallel folder it would be a real problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll switch to the main.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Version] [image: Status] [image: Documented]

This has been a discussion since the dawn of time, whether we should use only the file name or the entire reference. Hence, version 4.0 has two variables for that:

- `file` refers to the the file name, as `main.tex` (no directory reference), and
- `reference` refers to the full (normalized, canonical) path.

**Note:** You can take a look at the list of extracted directives in the log file (namely, `arara.log`, enabled with the `--log` command line option) and see the actual values for `file` and `reference`. Also observe that, for each element of `files`, the tool will add a directive of its own.

Sometimes we are restricted to the coverage of TeX tools, so we opted for the easiest solution. However, I must point out that version 4.0 allows project-based rules, so the cleanest solution in your case is to have:

- an `arara` configuration file, and
- a custom `pdflatex` rule with `reference` instead of `file`

Then

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ 'chapters/main.tex' ] }
```

will work as expected. Another possibility (way more advanced) is to keep `file` but change the working directory during command creation. I will present both solutions as follows.

Regarding security issues, we have a Turing-complete environment in the rule scope, so little to nothing could be done in this case. Deeply sorry. `:)`

So let us cover the possibilities. Here is a possible solution using a project-based configuration file and a modified engine rule (in this example, I will use `pdflatex`). First, I create the following configuration file (version 4.0 allows 4 names for the configuration file: `araraconfig.yaml`, `.araraconfig.yaml`, `arararc.yaml` and `.arararc.yaml`. I will use the first option. Note that there is a lookup order, so take a look at the user manual for more details):

`araraconfig.yaml` (placed at the root level of your project)

```
!config
paths:
- '.'
```

Now, let us copy the original [`pdflatex.yaml`](https://github.com/cereda/arara/blob/master/rules/pdflatex.yaml) rule to the root level of the project. Now, `pdflatex` directives will refer to this rule instead of the default one (as the `paths` key in the configuration file sets the current directory to be searchable first).

*First approach: replace `file` by `reference`*

This is the easiest solution. Simply replace lines 16 and 17 of `pdflatex.yaml`

```
    return getCommand('pdflatex', interaction, draft, shell,
           synctex, options, file);
```

by these two:

```
    return getCommand('pdflatex', interaction, draft, shell,
           synctex, options, reference);
```

Note that we simply replaced `file` by `reference`. That should suffice. The directive usage would be as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ 'chapters/main.tex' ] }
```

*Second approach: add a working directory option*

This solution involves adding an extra argument to our rule (we can append these lines to `pdflatex.yaml`):

```
- identifier: directory
  flag: >
    @{
        parameters.directory
    }
```

Now we should replace lines 16 and 17 of `pdflatex.yaml`

```
    return getCommand('pdflatex', interaction, draft, shell,
           synctex, options, file);
```

by these:

```
    if (isEmpty(directory)) {
        return getCommand('pdflatex', interaction, draft, shell,
               synctex, options, file);
    }
    else {
        return getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(directory, 'pdflatex',
               interaction, draft, shell, synctex, options, file);
    }
```

And then the directive usage should be along those lines:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ 'main.tex' ], directory: chapters }
```

Hope that helps! `:)`

Comment: im now using 4.0 and this does not work for me. Did this feature make it in to the last version bump?

Comment: @novski Hi, which feature are you referring to? `:)` I updated the answer in order to cover the two aforementioned approaches, hope that helps. `:)`

Comment: Eventually, I decided to compile from the main, I don't like to create a custom `pdflatex` directive, because I should create also a `biber` one and `myanyother` ones...