# Shortcut in Atom for compiling main.tex from other .tex-file

Tags: compiling, atom

I use `Atom` and have a `main.tex` file and use input to add text, which I write in separate `.tex` document, e.g. `\input{sections/introduction.tex}` occurs in the `main.tex-file`. If I am writing in a section, say `introduction.tex` and want to compile, then I need to open `main.tex` and build.

However, I would like to use a shortcut, such that I can compile from a section, e.g. i`ntroduction.tex`, without changing to `main.tex`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Is it an option to use arara? If so, perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100585/arara-making-a-rule-to-compile-the-main-file-from-a-chapter-file might be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

One can add the following at the top of the `.tex-file` one wish to compile from:
`% !TEX root = ../main.tex`

Comment: A note for anyone else not understanding why it doesn't work: the feature !TEX is not included in the basic LaTeX packages, one needs one of the "fancier" ones like latexer.